# Excel | How Can I Increment A Formula By 1 For A Group Of Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

Currently what is happening is that Im attempting to increment the formula +1.

for example here is what is in b1-b4:

```
Cell | Formula
b1   | =(mark!A8)& " - "& (Config!A4)
b2   | =(mark!A8)& " - "& (Config!A4)
b3   | =(mark!A8)& " - "& (Config!A4)
b4   | =(mark!A8)& " - "& (Config!A4)
```

if I select all 4 rows and paste it directly below "b4" it gives me this:

```
b5   | =(mark!A13)& " - "& (Config!A4)
b6   | =(mark!A13)& " - "& (Config!A4)
b7   | =(mark!A13)& " - "& (Config!A4)
b8   | =(mark!A13)& " - "& (Config!A4)
```

when I really want this:

```
b5   | =(mark!A9)& " - "& (Config!A4)
b6   | =(mark!A9)& " - "& (Config!A4)
b7   | =(mark!A9)& " - "& (Config!A4)
b8   | =(mark!A9)& " - "& (Config!A4)
```

How can I accomplish this? I only want it to increment +1 for every time I paste.

Comment: `Config!A4` should be updating as well, is that supposed to be an absolute reference?

Comment: yes its also a absolute reference however for whatever weird reason it never changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but here's the formula you need:

```
=(OFFSET(Mark!A$8,FLOOR.MATH((ROW()-1)/4),0))& " - "& (Config!$A$4)
```

`FLOOR.MATH()` rounds the result of its argument down to the nearest integer, and when used with `(ROW()-1)/4` ensures that we increment by one every four rows. (Note the use of absolute references with `$`)

Comment: Thank you! your Formula gave me exactly what I needed and with a tiny Modification I was able to make it work. With your explanation of the "(ROW()-1)/4" I was able to change it from "4" to "11" thus giving me exactly what I wanted in terms of copying and pasting.

The reason I needed it was because Im creating a mass Magento Products import for simple Products, The formulas Populate certain fields (name, size, color,) the reason for the 11 (in my case multiples of ten) is to copy each set of the sizes to a different row

Comment: I used this formula instead to get the end results:

=(OFFSET(MARK!A$8,FLOOR.MATH((ROW()-1)/11),0))& " - "& (Config!A5)

this way every 10 rows, it would change the product info in correlation to the number of sizes (ten sizes in my case)

Thanks alot for the help you really saved to at least a weeks worth of work down to a day.

Comment: @NinjaPanda in case it's easier for you, you don't need to copy paste in groups of ten, you can use the fill handle and drag down as far as you need.